# Wordpress peer to peer video chat(Admin to user) plugin or paid service

Tags: wordpress, video-streaming, html5-video, videochat

I have to implement Peer to peer video chat on WordPress recommend any integration or service from third party on economic price

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For P2P web based videochat there are 2 possible technologies:

- RTMFP using Adobe Flash
- WebRTC using HTML5

You can review some starting options by browsing the WP plugin repository for [WordPress Videochat Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/videochat/) or documentation and tutorials for [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/start/) or [RTMFP](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/p2p_rtmfp_groups.html) if you want to code everything yourself.

Comment: I would suggest to omit here Adobe Flash since WebRTC is a kind of standard these days, and Flash has a bad reputation.